# Display ActivityKit Live Activity View using local push notifications when app is in the background

Tags: ios, swift, activitykit, dynamic-island, widgetliveactivity

I am trying to create an app with live activity showing when user enters and exit a region. I have location manager setup and region setup in my app. App sends local push notification when user enters and exits a region. I want to show live activity view with push notification when user enters region. I tried using **'didEnterRegion'** delegate. But I am getting the error **Error requesting Live Activity: The operation couldn’t be completed. Target is not foreground.**. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. A Live Activity can only be started when the app is in foreground based on [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/displaying-live-data-with-live-activities#Start-the-Live-Activity).

Your best bet is to send the notification, have the user open your app, and start the Live Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Using actionable notification type can help you by guiding user for tap and hold it to add:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
       didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
       withCompletionHandler completionHandler: 
         @escaping () -> Void) {
       
   // Get the details from the original notification.
   let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        
   // Perform the task associated with the action.
   switch response.actionIdentifier {
   case "liveActivity":
      initiateLiveActivity(with: userInfo)
      break

   // Handle other actions…
   default:
      break
   }
    
   // Always call the completion handler when done.    
   completionHandler()
}
```

For remote push notifications, you need to prepare valid payload for this. More details about actionable notification from Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/declaring_your_actionable_notification_types).

Answer (score 0):

**Live activity can not start in application's background mode.** [apple_documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/displaying-live-data-with-live-activities#Start-the-Live-Activity) kindly read this