# how to start a liveActivity from a remote notification • Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-background-mode, activitykit

When implementing lock screen live activity widget for debugging purposes I had a button which runs `startLiveActivity()` function, app runs normaly widget appears totally functioning.

However I need this activity widget to appear whenever the app receives a remote push notification when the app is killed or in background, but it is appearing only when app is in foreground which doesn't really help the case here.

```swift
class LiveActivityHelper: ObservableObject {
    
    static var shared = LiveActivityHelper()
    
    @Published var activity: Activity<Attributes>? = nil

    func startLiveActivity() {
        
        let state = Attributes.ContentState()
        
        activity = try? Activity<Attributes>.request(attributes: Attributes(), contentState: state, pushType: nil)

    }
```

I tried running the `startLiveActivity()` function from appDelegate's didReceiveRemoteNotification:

```swift
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse) async {
        
        LiveActivityHelper.shared.startLiveActivity()
}
```

And from a notification extension I have:

```swift
class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {

    ...
    LiveActivityHelper.shared.startLiveActivity()
```

All these approaches lead to the same result, the widget appearing only when the app is opened.

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/updating-and-ending-your-live-activity-with-activitykit-push-notifications) included updating the widget from a remote notification but not how to start it using that approach.

Comment: Highly doubt Apple would allow this, background is very limited. Limited to only Background Modes and almost always restricted to the user triggering start.

Comment: how is updating a live activity widget in background is allowed and not creation?

Comment: You'll have to ask Apple, but probably because by launching the app the user has made a conscious action which results in starting the activity. If pushes can start the activity themselves, without user action, you could end up, hypothetically, with 100 different apps all trying to fight to start an activity at the same time via a push. How does the UI display 100 activities? Activities the user didn't even start?The user is always in control is behind the reasoning in every restriction Apple place on app developers.

Comment: Because the user has done something in your app to get it started. If an iOS user kills and app they don’t expect for that app to put something on their island, Lock Screen, etc. every app would be trying to put their live activity in the user’s eye. Every app is fighting for the user’s attention. Apple doesn’t allow apps to do stuff when they have been killed and very little can be done in the background. You need a very good reason and the user is well aware of this reason.

Comment: @loremipsum if so how can it be done?

Comment: Like I said in my first comment “Background Modes” is a start.

Comment: This answer on another post can give you an idea to initiate it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76403509/display-activitykit-live-activity-view-using-local-push-notifications-when-app-i/77514875#77514875

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now start a Live Activity with a push notification beginning with iOS 17.2 (currently in beta).

Request a `pushToStartToken` and use that to send a specific payload to your app. This will start a live activity & grant some background run time allowing you to get the live activity set up, grab the update token, etc.

More info:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/starting-and-updating-live-activities-with-activitykit-push-notifications

Answer (score 3):

Beginning with iOS 17.2, [you can now start a live activity with a push notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/starting-and-updating-live-activities-with-activitykit-push-notifications).

—————————————-

Up to iOS 17.1:

[A Live Activity can only be started while the app is in foreground](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/displaying-live-data-with-live-activities#Start-the-Live-Activity), because its purpose is to track a user-initiated feature, based on documentation.

Send your push notification, have your user open your app with it, then start the activity. Your desired flow is explicitly stated to be unsupported.

Comment: As of iOS 17.2, this is no longer true. Jim’s answer below describes how a Live Activity can be started from a push notification.